# Extract predicate from expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

HI Having that Linq query

```
    services.Get<Container>().Where(x => x.Approval.Status == "APPROVED")
```

How do I get Approval.Status == "APPROVED"

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Is `Where` a method you have control over or is it the regular Linq `Where` extension method? If it's yours, is the parameter type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`?

Comment: Look at the expression tree in the debugger to see how it is structured. Any specific problem?

Comment: And what do you actually want? The `Func<T, bool>` or the list of `true` and `false`? That'd be a switch from `Where` to `Select` - though I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Sorry guys, did not make much sense, Basically I am using RestSharp to talk to a Rest services so I am trying to create a kind of Linq to Rest so this command services.Get<Container>().Where(x => x.Approval.Status == "APPROVED") should be translated to "containers?approval.status=APPROVED" everything is generic and inferred from the lambdas

Answer (score 2):

This is MUCH harder to do than it seems. If the `Where` method is yours, and your parameter type is `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, you can get the predicate as easy as `myExpression.Body`.

But all you'll get out of that is an `Expression`, which could be literally anything. You own example is a binary expression of a member expression of a member expression of a parameter expression comparing against a Constant Expression. What happens if you call a method? Like this:

`services.Get<Container>().Where(x => x.IsStatus("APPROVED"))`

It'll result in a completely different expression that'll require completely different handling than in your example. Even if you don't permit method calls, you still have to parse the expression to confirm it isn't one.

And because Expressions aren't language specific, ToString() can be pretty unpredictable. It's like halfway between IL and C#.

Pretty much all you can do is build an expression parser, which is quite the undertaking. If this is something you want to delve into, check out [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx). It provides a convenient way to iterate over and parse an Expression as you need to.